# Have link to right of an input and the input take up the full remaining width with CSS?

Tags: css

This is a very basic question but I think inputs behave strangely so im struggling to find a solution.

I have a liquid width layout. I need a link to sit to the side of an input. I need the input to take up all the available width:

```
<a href="#">Information Link</a>
<input type="number" class="form-control form-control-default-new" placeholder="400">
```

[image]

If the input was a div I would just float the link the right and not have to do anything else. However if I make the input display block it wont take up the full width. And If I make it width 100% then it takes up the whole line and the link no longer sits along side it.

Comment: do you have the option to wrap that input in a div?

Comment: If needs be then yes

Comment: is something like this you want? http://jsfiddle.net/q8hk7fa8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wrap that input in a div container, you can achieve that effect pretty easy:

- `float right` for the `a` tag
- `overflow: hidden` to the `div container` of the `input`
- set `input` `width to 100%`
- done.

Check out the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/bx584913/)**

```css
a{
    float: right;
}
div{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
input{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Information Link</a>
<div><input type="number" class="form-control form-control-default-new" placeholder="400"/></div>
```

Comment: Just add `input { box-sizing:border-box; }` to fix the padding of the input not being constrained to the parent div.

Comment: @Marcelo added. You can play around with this trick with margin & padding and not worry someones gonna fall off the row :)

Answer (score 0):

Example with `display: block` and `float: left` :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a, input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%
}

input {
  width: 80%
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control form-control-default-new" placeholder="400">
<a href="#">Information Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. The `white-space: nowrap` CSS prevents the second cell (with the link) from line-breaking and the `width: 100%` on the first cell makes that cell grow as large as the table will allow it to (i.e. until the cell runs into the second cell with the nowrap restriction.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bx584913/3/)**

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.container div {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.link {
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.input-box {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-default-new" placeholder="400" />
    </div>
    <div class="link"> 
        <a href="#">Information Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the desired width for the input fields, like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwpBoK

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 12px;
}
.text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;

}
.container {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.form-control form-control-default-new {
  width: 400px;

}


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    <p>I need this:</p>
  </div>
<div class="container">

<input type="number" class="form-control form-control-default-new" placeholder="400"><a href="#">Information Link</a>

</div>
</div>
```